# Google Apps Scripts : Cannot Find Method saveAndClose

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created a google form and am creating an auto generated appointment letter using the values in the fields. An event is triggered on form submit and its named Values are passed to a function which replaces certain placeholders in a document. Here is that function.

```
 function createEvent_ (namedValues) {
 var options = {
 cand_name : namedValues["Candidate Name"],
 cand_email : namedValues["Candidate's Email"],
 mgr_name : namedValues["Manager's Name"],
 mgr_email : namedValues["Manager's Email"],
 mgr_desig : namedValues["Manager's Designation"],
 rep_off : namedValues["Reporting Officer"],
 ctc : namedValues["Gross Monthly CTC"],
 prob : namedValues["Probation Period"],
 pos_off : namedValues["Position Offered"],
 doj : namedValues["Date of Joining"].toString(),
 date : namedValues["Date"],
};
var email_address = "ravi.prakash@iglulabs.com";  
var docTemplate = "1zgJadsQCJKcSmOQkNN4_Er64w210NOwLIM2-f3jwa94";  
var docName = "Auto Generated Offer Letter";
//Make a copy of template to work on  
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName +' for '+ options.cand_name).getId();

//Open the Cloned Template  
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();



//Replace Dummy values in template with form values  
copyBody.replaceText('CANDIDATE_NAME', options.cand_name);
copyBody.replaceText('MANAGER_NAME', options.mgr_name);
copyBody.replaceText('MANAGER_DESIGNATION', options.mgr_desig);
copyBody.replaceText('REPORTING_OFFICER', options.rep_off);
copyBody.replaceText('CTC_MONTHLY', options.ctc);
copyBody.replaceText('PROBATION_PERIOD', options.prob);
copyBody.replaceText('TODAYS_DATE', options.date);
copyBody.replaceText('MANAGER_EMAIL', options.mgr_email);
copyBody.replaceText('POSITION_OFFERED', options.pos_off);
copyDoc.saveAndClose(options.cand_email);


//Create Calendar Event
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('iglulabs.com_dlp3rl3fnhcsvothirocdgspck@group.calendar.google.com');
var event = cal.createEvent(options.cand_name + ' Decathlon Review', new Date('October 29, 2014 01:55:00 PM'), new Date('October 29, 2014 02:55:00 PM'), {guests: options.cand_email, sendInvites: true , description : "You can fill out your responses at : " + "https://docs.google.com/a/iglulabs.com/forms/d/1Ysbl2C8VbWFguTRIjDaCjZDh5HlTDwFGh0eGEEqT57I/viewform"});
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());

var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");  //Get the saved template as pdf to mail
var link = 'https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8iBopZLR9-sbXJJNkN3MkNLbnM&usp=sharing';
var subject = "Mail For My Offer Letter";
var body = "Hello, PFA attached the offer letter";

MailApp.sendEmail(options.mgr_email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: [pdf], cc:email_address});
DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true); //Delete Temp File 

}
```

Everything including the trigger is working fine. If I comment out the saveAndClose it sends the auto generated mail but without the placeholders replaced. It was working completely fine until a while ago but suddenly it has started crashing. I don't recall any changes I made. Secondly, (I know I'm supposed to put this in a separate post) , yesterday it started throwing that the function makeCopy() is not found. I'm so confused as to how to debug it. Is the Google Apps Script still under Experimentation ?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess... is the heading for the column containing the candidate's names supposed to be `"Candidate's Name"`? You've got this in your code, and both the errors you're seeing are related to `cand_name`:

```
 cand_name : namedValues["Candidate Name"],
```

If the expected named value is not passed from the form handling code, then `options.cand_name` will be `undefined`. You can't trust it.

---

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveAndClose%28%29), `Document.saveAndClose()` takes no parameters. Yet you're passing `options.cand_email` for some reason.The error message you're receiving probably complains that it can't find `saveAndClose(string)` or something similar. If `options.cand_name` is null, that could also be the problem.

> I don't recall any changes I made.

Take a look in "File > See revision history", to be sure.

> ... makeCopy() is not found

Is not found *in what*? You've got that method in this line (reformatted for clarity):

```
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
                     .makeCopy(docName +' for '+ options.cand_name)
                     .getId();
```

If `DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)` fails to find the expected file, then it will return `null`. The Null object does not have a `makeCopy()` method, which is one possible way that you could receive an error.

A second way, assuming the file was found, would be to pass an unexpected parameter to `makeCopy()`. Once again, there's `options.cand_name`, and if it's null then `docName +' for '+ options.cand_name` will be `undefined`, and will fail.

#### Suggestion

Add default handling or error checking to this code:

```
 var options = {
 cand_name : namedValues["Candidate Name"],
 cand_email : namedValues["Candidate's Email"],
 mgr_name : namedValues["Manager's Name"],
 mgr_email : namedValues["Manager's Email"],
 mgr_desig : namedValues["Manager's Designation"],
 rep_off : namedValues["Reporting Officer"],
 ctc : namedValues["Gross Monthly CTC"],
 prob : namedValues["Probation Period"],
 pos_off : namedValues["Position Offered"],
 doj : namedValues["Date of Joining"].toString(),
 date : namedValues["Date"],
};
```